# How to call a JavaScript function on page load event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling, tinymce

I am calling a JavaScript function in a page to load an event as follows:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script12", "Disable();", true);
```

The `Disable()` function is:

```
function Disable() {
   var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
   ed.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
}
```

But, when my page loads, it is not working as intended.
Are there any obvious errors in my code?
Is my `Disable()` function implemented correctly?

Comment: Do you see an error in the Javascript Console?

Comment: i dont khow how to use javascirpt Console

Comment: It's different for every browser. [This should help..](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=how+to+use+javascript+console).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery ready function.
Just include the reference of jQuery library (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) in your page & call like this.

```
<script src="../jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 Disable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Only if the OP is already using jQuery. Adding jQuery for `document.ready()` alone is crazy talk.

Comment: jQuery now, by default, ships with VS 2010 default project templates. So, it is better to use a cross browser library instead of writing your custom code. So its worth using jQuery.